# neo4j database started via windows service not accessible remotely

Tags: neo4j

I am setting up window service for my neo4j database.  I am able to start that from service and I can do a http post cypher query using localhost.  However, I can't connect to the neo4j db remotely.

If I start the neo4j db via neo4j Desktop, I can perform http post both locally and remotely.

When I compared the neo4j logs generated using service start vs neo4j desktop start, they are quite different but no error on the service one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By default, **Neo4j server is not accessible remotely.**

You need to change **$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf**.

Find this line:

```
#dbms.connector.http.address=localhost:7474
```

And Replace it with:

```
dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474
```

Setting connector address to **0.0.0.0** makes it accessible remotely.

Comment: I already have http address set to 0.0.0:7474.  Any other idea?

Comment: Did you restart the database after restart?

Comment: The configuration file has been that way and I restarted with that conf file previously.  Thanks.